# Symbolize Subscript doesn't work

Tags: symbols, input-alias

I want *Mathematica* to interpret subscripted variables as symbols. I found documentation suggesting the `Notation` package could do this, but if I do:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
x = 1
Subscript[x, 1]
```

I still get:

> ```
> 1
> Subscript[1, 1]
> ```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be recognised as symbols the subscripted forms need to be keyed in `control-_`, you cannot explicitly use `Subscript`:

[image]

When you use `Subscript[]` the arguments are replaced by their values before being passed to the function, but if you do `x` `Ctrl+_` `1` the `Notation` package can grab it before the replacement.

Comment: Ok I got it. In case you know how to tell subscript not to replace it's arguments by their values, I'd be still interested.

Comment: @PeMa You could SetAttributes HoldFirst or HoldAll for Subscript http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html

Comment: Well that's not gonna work I think. If I have e.g. phi and phi_L I don't want phi not to be evaluated, but of course not inside phi_L.

Comment: Just checked: `SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldAll]` indeed prevents the value substitution, but the result still is not recognized as a symbol that can for example be used in the function definition pattern.